# Is there ability to call database procedure from Laravel controller function?

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, laravel-8, oracle10g

I have code that do multi processes and it takes time to perform them and error timeout appear so I think to make the code inside database procedure and call it from controller function . is it a right solution or there is another technical solution ,**please help me?**

I have Setting more max_execution_time but I think its not a right solution .

Comment: That’s why people invented jobs .. and Tinder!

Comment: Stored procedures is not a solution to the problem you are describing. If they take time, you want them to be executed outside of the http cycle. Consider using Background Tasks & Job Queues. Also consider using explain that can provide insights into the database's query execution plan

Comment: Laravel does offer a robust scheduling system. Check more here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#writing-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel terminable callback that will execute those after the response is sent to FE for example. Then fe must do subsequent request with 'is it ready yet?' like requests.

PS. query times are not included into the php execution time limit.

Or you can dispatch jobs instead of that terminable callback, but jobs have also a timeout.

If you are trying to download something, then you can stream the response to fe (for csv for example, as xls is not posible because php excel lib does not support it, just excel js lib knows how to stream data from the browser's memory to disk).

Comment: my code is to do multi mathematics process to calculate multi variables for people in an array than insert the records in database . In fact ,the process take a long time . Does Laravel terminable callback solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes if it does not timeout. The response will be sent like: ok. I will do it and then the callback will do the work.